Merge data with overlapping dates in oracle
I have data in 2 tables and I need to split/and merge the data from table1 based on the data in table2 by looking for any overlaps in both.  Can anybody provide tips to get this done in oracle?
Table1:
Col1 Col2   start_date     end_date     Quantity
I1  L2      28/Nov/2023    31/Dec/2024  20
I1  L2      24/Jun/2024    11/Jul/2024  6
I1  L2      10/Jul/2024    20/Jul/2024  8


Table2
Col1 Col2   start_date     end_date     Quantity
I1  L2      05/Jul/2024    14/Jul/2024  48
I1  L2      12/Jul/2024    10/Sep/2024  60


Now split the data from table1 referring to the overlaps within table1 based on col1 and col2 matches and also on table2 on same columns match and output should be like below. Any data in tab1 that does not overlap with data from tab2 should be discarded.
Output:

Col1        Col2    start_date     end_date     Quantity
21397550    1688    5-Jul-24       9-Jul-24     26 (20+6)
21397550    1688    10-Jul-24      14-Jul-24    14 (8+6) 
21397550    1688    15-Jul-24      20-Jul-24    28 (20+8)
   

Below are the create DDLs for tab1 and tab2
create table tab1 as
select 'I1' col1, 'L2' col2, to_date('28nov2023','ddmonyyyy') start_date, to_date('31dec2024','ddmonyyyy') end_date, 20 quantity from dual
union
select 'I1' col1, 'L2' col2, to_date('24jun2024','ddmonyyyy') start_date, to_date('11jul2024','ddmonyyyy') end_date, 6 quantity from dual
union
select 'I1' col1, 'L2' col2, to_date('10jul2024','ddmonyyyy') start_date, to_date('20jul2024','ddmonyyyy') end_date, 8 quantity from dual


create table tab2 as
select 'I1' col1, 'L2' col2, to_date('5jul2024','ddmonyyyy') start_date, to_date('14jul2024','ddmonyyyy') end_date, 48 quantity from dual
union
select 'I1' col1, 'L2' col2, to_date('12jul2024','ddmonyyyy') start_date, to_date('10sep2024','ddmonyyyy') end_date, 60 quantity from dual


Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; a complete explanation of the logic that you want to implement ("Now split the data from table1 referring to table2" is not a comprehensible explanation as it does not tell us why or how the values should be split); your attempt at a solution; and the issues/errors with your solution. At the moment the logic of how to get from your sample data to the final output is missing from the question so it is unanswerable.

Also, what do dates have to do with your question because the sample data contains no dates.

Also, you go from having input data with a Quantity column to output data with a Price column; what is the relationship between Quantity and Price? Usually the two are different concepts that are (mostly) unrelated.

@MT0 - I updated my question with all required details and DDLs. Hope I am not missing anything for viewers to be clear.

Please [edit] the question to include a complete explanation of the logic ("Now split the data from table1 referring to the overlaps within table1 based on col1 and col2 matches and also on table2 on same columns match" does not explain what you want to achieve) and why the outputs are 26, 14 and 20 for those date ranges because there does not appear to be a logical method to reach that result.

You can limit the rows to those in table that overlap a row in table2 and restrict the start_date and end_dateto the minimum and maximum bounds defined bytable2`.
Then you can unpivot the dates so you have a sequence of start- and end-dates and then generate a running total by adding the quantity at the start-date and subtract the quantity at the end-date.
Then
Like this:
WITH overlapping (col1, col2, start_date, end_date, quantity) AS (
  SELECT t1.col1,
         t1.col2,
         GREATEST(t1.start_date, t2.min_date),
         LEAST(t1.end_date, t2.max_date),
         t1.quantity
  FROM   table1 t1
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT MIN(t2.start_date) AS min_date,
                  MAX(t2.end_date) AS max_date
           FROM   table2 t2
           WHERE  t1.col1 = t2.col1
           AND    t1.col2 = t2.col2
           AND    t1.start_date < t2.end_date
           AND    t1.end_date > t2.start_date
         ) t2  
),
running_totals (col1, col2, start_date, end_date, quantity) AS (
  SELECT col1,
         col2,
         dt,
         LEAD(dt - INTERVAL '1' SECOND)
           OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY dt),
         SUM(quantity * sign)
           OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY dt)
  FROM   overlapping
         UNPIVOT (
           dt FOR sign IN (
             start_date AS +1,
             end_date   AS -1
           )
         )
)
SELECT *
FROM   running_totals
WHERE  start_date < end_date

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Col1, Col2, start_date, end_date, Quantity) AS
SELECT 'I1', 'L2', DATE '2023-11-28', DATE '2024-12-31', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I1', 'L2', DATE '2024-06-24', DATE '2024-07-11',  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I1', 'L2', DATE '2024-07-10', DATE '2024-07-20',  8 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 (Col1, Col2, start_date, end_date, Quantity) AS
SELECT 'I1', 'L2', DATE '2024-07-05', DATE '2024-07-14', 48 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I1', 'L2', DATE '2024-07-12', DATE '2024-09-10', 60 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



COL1
COL2
START_DATE
END_DATE
QUANTITY




I1
L2
2024-07-05 00:00:00
2024-07-09 23:59:59
26


I1
L2
2024-07-10 00:00:00
2024-07-10 23:59:59
34


I1
L2
2024-07-11 00:00:00
2024-07-19 23:59:59
28


I1
L2
2024-07-20 00:00:00
2024-09-09 23:59:59
20



Note: This does not get your expected output but it does split the data based on the overlaps and total the result like you have asked; the expected output does not appear to match your sample data.
fiddle

Thanks. This gives some rough idea on what to be done. I will tweak it to get desired results.

Far to be finished but at least give you idea where to go and outputs your step1 results:
with table1(Col1, Col2, Dt1, Dt2, Quantity) as (
    select 'I1', 'L1', 'D2', 'D90', 19 union all
    select 'I1', 'L1', 'D6', 'D18', 6
),
table2(Col1, Col2, Dt1, Dt2, Quantity) as (
    select 'I1', 'L1', 'D10', 'D25', 10 union all
    select 'I1', 'L1', 'D12', 'D42', 20
)
, stable1(Col1, Col2, tag1, Dt1, tag2, Dt2, Quantity) as (
    select Col1, col2, substr(Dt1,1, 1), to_number(substr(Dt1,2))
        , substr(Dt2,1, 1), to_number(substr(Dt2,2))
        , Quantity from table1
)
, stable2(Col1, Col2, tag1, Dt1, tag2, Dt2, Quantity) as (
    select Col1, col2, substr(Dt1,1, 1), to_number(substr(Dt1,2))
        , substr(Dt2,1, 1), to_number(substr(Dt2,2))
        , Quantity from table2
)
, mtable2(col1, col2, tag1, tag2, dt1, dt2) as (
    select * 
    from stable2
    match_recognize (
        partition by col1, col2, tag1, tag2
        order by Dt1, Dt2
        measures first(Dt1) as dt1_start, max(dt2) as dt2_end
        pattern( merged strt* ) 
        define
            merged as max(dt2) >= next(dt1)
        
    )
)
select t1.col1, t1.col2 ,
    t1.tag1||greatest(t1.dt1, t2.dt1) as dt1,
    t1.tag2||least(t1.dt2, t2.dt2) as dt2,
    t1.quantity
    
from stable1 t1
join mtable2 t2 on 
    t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 and t1.tag1 = t2.tag2
    and -- check overlaps
    greatest(t1.col2, t1.col2) >= least(t1.col1, t2.col1)
;

I1  L1  D10 D42 19
I1  L1  D10 D18 6

